# PostgreSQL "column "foo" does not exist" where foo is the value

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to perform an Update query on a Postgres db from Node, and I'm running into this weird issue:

```
'UPDATE salesforce.Guest__c SET currently_at_property__c = "foo" WHERE rewards_id ='+rewardsId,
```

I'm trying to set the `currently_at_property__c` equal to the value "foo" but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
error: "column "foo" does not exist"
```

I don't know why this is happening, since foo is the value, NOT the column.

Comment: Use single quotes for a text literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct with the right quote:

```
    'UPDATE salesforce.Guest__c SET currently_at_property__c = 'foo' WHERE rewards_id ='+rewardsId,
```

Comment: It was a problem with the quotes. Thanks! Here is what I ended up with:  "UPDATE salesforce.Guest__c SET currently_at_property__c = '' WHERE rewards_id__c ='123456'"